How do I remove this mess from my terminal?
I upgraded to 24.04. Now in my terminal it will show something like [#.###s] before every prompt. How do I get rid of this, and also the previous exit code? Say I hit ctrl+C. It would show something like "[1.191s] 130  tim@fileserver:~$" How do I get rid of that stuff?
Is there a way to get it to auto-quote filenames? I use clink on Windows, and that does it. Is there any way for it to stop escaping exclamation points in filenames?
Thank you.
Solved:
PS1 echoed \[\e[38;5;202m\]\$(byobu_prompt_status)\[\e[00m\]\$(byobu_prompt_runtime) \[\e[38;5;245m\]\u\[\e[00m\]@\[\e[38;5;172m\]\h\[\e[00m\]:\[\e[38;5;5m\]\w\[\e[00m\]\$(byobu_prompt_symbol)
I browsed over to ~/.byobu/ and saw a file prompt. I opened it. It pointed to /usr/share/byobu/profiles/bashrc.
I commented out the first line of prompt and copied the contents of /usr/share/byobu/profiles/bashrc to it. On the line where it says export PS1= I removed \[\e[38;5;202m\]\$(byobu_prompt_status)\[\e[00m\]\$(byobu_prompt_runtime) .
All fixed, and thank you to @steeldriver for pointing me in the right direction.

Please post the exact message before the prompt

I did. They are return statuses from the last command. One shows execution time from last to current line ( [#.###s] ) and the other one is the exit code from the previous process ran.

Please ask one topic per question. Assuming you are using a bash shell, you probably added the time and status to your primary prompt string or prompt command - something similar to How can I automatically time commands in bash?. Please [edit] your question to include the outputs of echo "$PS1" and echo "$PROMPT_COMMAND".

Thank you "steeldriver" for the help in pointing me where to look. It turns out that there was byobu stuff inserted via byobu. I had to edit to "prompt" file under my .byobu directory.
I really just commented out the first reference line copied the contents of where "prompt" pointed to (/usr/share/byobu/profiles/bashrc) and deleted the few references where it assigned the PS1 variable. The problems were "byobu_prompt_status" and "byobu_prompt_runtime".
